# Azure CLI non-interactive login in GUIless VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am working on Win 10 with Virtual Box/Vagrant not WSL. Everyday I struggling with interactive login. I am working on subscriptions which do not allow for service principals.

**The question is how to do `az login` in GUIless VM with 2FA enabled?**

Is it somehow possible to login in Windows and move the login info after 2FA to my VM?(Something like exporting k8s config from aks) Maybe some terminal hack like using lynx-like(headless browser with js) or enter the app code in CLI.

Am I really forced to use WSL? Note I don't want to have hyper-v enabled, as I am not able to provision static IP for my VMs without another hacking.

Answer (score 2):

As I know. it's impossible to set the 2FA in the VM for `az login` with interactive login. And but copy the access info is an available way. You can copy all the files to the VM path `/home/username/.azure/`. Then you can use the Azure CLI command without doing the `az login`. But it's not security, I recommend you just cloud do it for the test.

Comment: Great at least just copying the files is working. I can share this folders to VM and just login once in Win. Just to be clear I don't want to stop using 2FA just I'd like to use it even on CLI, so some headless browser is also fine for me. But I have not been able to find any working solution there is lot going on on background of this login box.

Comment: @Zveratko That's the problem. Even if you enable the 2FA, you also need to interact with the browser to choose the way to authenticate. So it's impossible to do the no-interactive login.

Comment: @Zveratko What's favor else I can do for you? If it works for you and no more questions, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I am looking for solution done with some ['headless'](https://help.apify.com/en/articles/1640711-how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-puppeteer) browser. As they can do what normal browser do it must be somehow possible to do it.